# in jmeter script pipeline execution error was 'inputversionnotvalidversion (input version not valid version )''

Tags: azure-pipelines, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

in jmeter script pipeline execution error was
##[error]Error: InputVersionNotValidVersion $(JMeterInstaller.JMeterVersion)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AS96W.png)

in jmeter script pipeline execution error was 'inputversionnotvalidversion (input version not valid version )'' reslove

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're suffering from [this issue](https://github.com/algattik/azure-pipelines-jmeter-extension/issues/19), to wit using a non-default name for the task.

So if you revert all the task names to their respective defaults it should resolve your problem.

More information:

- [JMeter Tool Installer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AlexandreGattiker.jmeter-tasks&targetId=b3772dec-bbd7-4665-8816-435b70a37044)
- [How to Run JMeter Scripts in Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/kb/Basic1/#How-to-Run-JMeter-Scripts-in-Taurus)
- [Execute JMeter script Using Taurus](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wVSbalE_Nh8)